# Move button up next to select

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I move the red - button to be up next to the top of the control?

[image: screenshot]

The HTML looks like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="assigned-tenants" class="col-md-4 control-label">Assigned Tenants</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <select size="10" class="form-control" id="assigned-tenants" name="assignedTenants">
                <option value="1">fdsaf</option>
            </select>

            <button ata-toggle="tooltip" title="Add" class="btn btn-danger">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use the bootstrap class `pull-left` to your first element in that column which is select box.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="assigned-tenants" class="col-md-4 control-label">Assigned Tenants</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="col-md-10 pull-left" style="padding-right:0px">
                <select size="10" class="form-control" id="assigned-tenants" name="assignedTenants" class="pull-left">
                    <option value="1">fdsaf</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 pull-left" style="padding-left:0px">
                <button ata-toggle="tooltip" title="Add" class="btn btn-danger pull-left">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
               </button>
           </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: That didn't work, the padding was wrong, please take a look at my original post, I have now added a code snippet.

Comment: There is too much padding now (from the column inside the column) and it does not allow with the other elements on the page.

Comment: I have updated the answer, check the code now, padding is 0, You can adjust by giving some more padding to the style.

Comment: Yeah, I have just adjusted the margins and padding and it is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use vertical-align:top; in the css for that button.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="assigned-tenants" class="col-md-4 control-label">Assigned Tenants</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <select size="10" id="assigned-tenants" name="assignedTenants">
                <option value="1">fdsaf</option>
            </select>

            <button ata-toggle="tooltip" title="Add" class="btn btn-danger" style="vertical-align:top;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was working but adding form-control to the select messes it up.